# Can I use xxf:get-session-attribute() to get attributes from the Proxy Portlet's session?

Tags: orbeon

In the Orbeon Proxy Portlet, I have set this configuration in `liferay-portlet.xml`:

`<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>`

I have the same configuration in another portlet where I am setting a session attribute like `LIFERAY_SHARED_MYATTRIBUTE`. Note that the `LIFERAY_SHARED_` prefix is required to share session attributes between portlets in Liferay.

When I call `xxf:get-session-attribute('LIFERAY_SHARED_MYATTRIBUTE')` in a Calculated Value for a field when using the Proxy Portlet, I get no value. Should I take this to mean that this function only works for getting session attributes on the Orbeon server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portlet is just a proxy to the servlet where Form Runner actually runs.

In order to share session attributes between Form Runner (running in a servlet) and a portlet, they would have to:

- run in the same container
- have the same session id

But currently the session between the browser and the proxy portlet (so the Liferay session) and the session between the proxy portlet and Form Runner are different.

So I don't think that session sharing can take place this way.